# CSI (Channel State Information) from TP-LINK router

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have came across some research papers where CSI (Channel State Information) is being used for human activity recognition (movement) or sometimes to obtain indoor positioning.

Now, I want to install this CSI tool in my laptop (Ubuntu installed as VM) and "Intel Dual Band wireless AC-3165" Wi-fi card (laptop builtin) and then extract the data from a TP-link router (Model No. TL-WR940N). The procedure for installation is given in the following link.

> http://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/index.html

There is no particular error but it says "`no such file or directory`" while I run `cd linux-80211n-csitool` in step 2.

Question:

1. I wanted to be sure, if the CSI tool works only with Intel 5300 NIC and not with any others.
2. If not with any other, then is any other CSI tool available online which can be installed in my wifi card to get the desired data (like - amplitude/phase) of wireless signals.

Comment: @n8te That comment should be an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the CSI Tool in question requires the installation of modified firmware and drivers specifically for the Intel 5300 NIC, it will not work with Wi-Fi card in your laptop.

From the [FAQ](https://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/faq.html) of the CSI Tool site you provided:

> *4. Does the CSI Tool work with a different Intel device (e.g., IWL 6300)?*
>
> **No. The tool relies on my custom firmware image which only works on
>   the IWL 5300.**

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Though off topic, but is there any way to get such information using OpenWRT or something similar ?

Comment: @Nusrat: The problem is that WLAN drivers normally don't make this information available. So you need a hacked driver, and that will only work for specific hardware. The router "distribution" (OpenWRT, whatever) makes no difference. If you have different hardware, you need to hack the driver yourself (which is not trivial).